# HTML forms to python code in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am able to run all cells except the last one from this colab page.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/deeplab_demo.ipynb

There is a form in the section "Run on sample images". How do I use script instead of that form? I am using Jupyter notebook that does not support creation of the forms like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double click the form in colab you can see the code that sits behind it:

```py
SAMPLE_IMAGE = 'image1'  # @param ['image1', 'image2', 'image3']
IMAGE_URL = ''  #@param {type:"string"}

_SAMPLE_URL = ('https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/'
               'deeplab/g3doc/img/%s.jpg?raw=true')


def run_visualization(url):
  """Inferences DeepLab model and visualizes result."""
  try:
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    jpeg_str = f.read()
    original_im = Image.open(BytesIO(jpeg_str))
  except IOError:
    print('Cannot retrieve image. Please check url: ' + url)
    return

  print('running deeplab on image %s...' % url)
  resized_im, seg_map = MODEL.run(original_im)

  vis_segmentation(resized_im, seg_map)


image_url = IMAGE_URL or _SAMPLE_URL % SAMPLE_IMAGE
run_visualization(image_url)
```

If you copy this code as is into a new cell in your own jupyter instance you can now just fill whatever values you like for the `@param` fields and run the cell as normal.